# Where is the error list in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I used to develop a habit in Eclipse to use Error List to check errors and warnings. Is there something like that in IntelliJ IDEA? I don't see it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eclipse incrementally builds the whole project all the time and finds all compilation errors even in classes you haven't touched/opened at all.

IntelliJ is not building your whole code base upon every change so there is no such view. The closest you can get is *Messages* view (available under <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>) but it only shows compilation errors discovered when a file with errors was physically opened (or when the whole project was built).

## UPDATE

IntelliJ IDEA 12 will most likely have [incremental compilation feature](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12+EAP):

> Currently supported: incremental compilation of Java, Groovy, resource copying, UI Designer forms, Artifacts, Android, annotation processing, not-null instrumentation

Comment: Any reasons to why this is so? Why won't they give an option to enable/disable compile-as-you-type feature? any links? But messages view is cool.

Comment: Oh, that's why: it takes lots of time to recompile the whole thing to find errors as you type, and it doesn't have incr compilation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to look at tiny red stripes on the scrollbar to find where the errors in a file are located (they couldn't make it less convenient to use :/)